# Jasper Rest service not giving images and charts

Tags: java, rest, jasperserver

Hi am using jasper rest V2 to fetch data from jsper server as html and displaying it in the browser. It fetches the report but not the images and charts. How can i get the images and charts.

Comment: What are you using to fetch the image?

Comment: I have been using Images in my reports and i just set the Image expression as "repo:/images/filename" and it does the job fine.

Comment: now am using Visualization.js and its works fine... When i use rest V2 the image url comes as attachment. Could you please explain how you did it?

Comment: I am using VisualizeJs as well. But not using rest V2 for the images. There are a set of images i use with my reports and i have deployed those images on my Jasper server. Placed image components on the report with the image expression as "repo:/images/filename". it works fine.

Comment: Before using visualization.js i was using restV2 to get reports. That reports contains images and charts which comes as not found

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about this. http://imgur.com/tV1jhT0

Comment: check if the directory that contains the images has the right permits. I dropped jasper and started using wkhtmltopdf....sooo much better and easier

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<dependency>
                <groupId>com.jaspersoft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jrs-rest-java-client</artifactId>
                <version>[5.5.0.2-ALPHA-SNAPSHOT,]</version>
</dependency>`

And Artifact has been already deployed. It's strange that it doen's work.
Try to remove square brackets around the version
`<version>5.5.0.2-ALPHA-SNAPSHOT</version>`

And this could be your HtmlReport Mehtod

```
@Override
    public HtmlReport getHtmlReport(String path, Map<String, String> params) {
        Session session = openAdminSession();

        ReportExecutionRequest executionRequest = buildReportExecutionRequest(path, ReportOutputFormat.HTML);
        ReportExecutionDescriptor executionDescriptor = buildReportExecutionDescriptor(executionRequest, session);

        ExportDescriptor exportDescriptor = buildExportDescriptor(executionDescriptor);

        HtmlReport report = session
                .reportingService()
                .reportExecutionRequest(executionDescriptor.getRequestId())
                .export(exportDescriptor.getId())
                .htmlReport(exportDescriptor);

        return report;
    }
```